# Adding an unlisted group in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, user-accounts, file-permissions

I accidentally removed the "staff" group from a set of folder permissions and I have no idea how to get it back.

Is there a way to get it back, and if so how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite sure what you mean here.  You lost the `staff` group declaration in `/etc/group`?

```
mress:10003 Z$ dscl . cat /Groups/staff
AppleMetaNodeLocation: /Local/Default
GeneratedUID: ABCDEFAB-CDEF-ABCD-EFAB-CDEF00000014
GroupMembers: FFFFEEEE-DDDD-CCCC-BBBB-AAAA00000000
GroupMembership: root
Password: *
PrimaryGroupID: 20
RealName: Staff
RecordName: staff
RecordType: dsRecTypeStandard:Groups
SMBSID: S-1-5-32-545
mress:10004 Z$ grep '^staff' /etc/group
staff:*:20:root
```

The file definition is only used before Directory Services is started during boot — and I suspect not even then.

If you mean the folders are no longer in group `staff`, use `chown staff` to fix them.  Alternately, use `/Applications/Utility/Disk Utility.app`, select your boot drive from the sidebar, and click "Repair Disk Permissions".

Comment: I have a folder, and I was changing the permissions in the Get Info window and I removed staff, and need to get it back.

Comment: OK, use the Repair Disk Permissions thing I mentioned above.

Comment: It's not an Apple installed folder. Will this do anything?

Comment: Did it come from an installable package (`pkg` or `mpkg`)?  If so, there's a permissions record for it.  If not... I'd wonder why it's using group `staff` to start with.  At worst, though, you can use Terminal:  `sudo chgrp staff folder`.

Comment: No. I made it. I use it as my root folder for Apache and I had been using ~/Sites, but then I made a new folder in my Dropbox to sync across computers. I just copied the Sites folder into Dropbox and renamed it. My Apache daemon was running under the staff group, because I needed access to some staff only folders, so this folder needed to be a staff folder too. I copied the Sites folder again so it has permissions now, and I changed some otherns so that I could put Apache back under the _www group. All is good now. Thanks for the help. :) (I probably should've given those details before..)